# How to properly specify on code-documentation a function may return null on C#?

Tags: c#, xml, documentation, xml-documentation, code-documentation

I'm creating some code-documentation and I want to properly display that the function may return null if the resource isn't found.

Dummy method with some code-documentation I created, having GhostDoc auto generated documentation as a base:

```
///<summary>Gets something for the specified unique identifier.</summary>
///<param name="id">Something's unique identifier.</param>
///<returns>Something if found; otherwise <c>null</c>.</returns>
private Something GetSomethingById(int id)
{ }
```

I'm currently using the XML tag < c > around Null but I wanted to know if that's the best/correct way.

Comment: Why do you think your example is wrong?

Comment: I'm not assuming it's wrong, it's just the way I'm doing it. I just wanted to know if there's a better way to do it or a more standard way, in C# at least.

Comment: Your approach has a precedent - see any of Microsoft's online documentation.  When they refer to `null`, it's done with a monospaced font as code

Comment: @Ian You mean something like this: https://www.helixoft.com/blog/guidelines-to-better-xml-doc-comments-and-documentation.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, after some digging into Microsoft code, i.e., decompiling some DLLs, I found they are using the following standard: `<paramref name="sourceTimeZone" /> is <see langword="null" />.`

The example was extracted from the System.TimeZoneInfo.

Don't know if this was what @Ian was referencing on his comment.